# How would I go About Getting a Global Variables value in another form?

Tags: c#, .net

So I am new to Programming and I am working In Visual Studios c# Windows application Forms,
and I have a button on the first form That needs to set a Glabel Bool To true when pressed while also opening the second form.

On the second forms startup I need it to tell if that bool is set to true or false, to enable a button(on the second Form) or keep it disabled(if False.

Here Is the First Forms Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class FirstPage: Form
    {
        public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IsManager = false;

        public static class Global
        {
            public static bool IsManager = false;
        }

        private void Button_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.hide();  
            Form2 f2 = new form2(IsManager);
            f2.ShowDialog();

            IsManager = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my second Forms Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class SecondPage : Form
    {
        public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsManager = isManager;
        }
        private bool isManager;

        private void setButtonVisibility()
        {
            if(isManager == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button Message Display")
            }
        {


        //Need to check if the Global variable is true or false on page load to set a button to either enabled or disabled
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense If not let me know :) Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acomplish this by passing the variable to the constructor of the second form.
Let's assume you want to send the `IsManager` value to the second form. Call the second form while passing the value to the constructor:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(IsManager);
```

In the second form, read the value:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private bool IsManager;
    public Form2(bool isManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsManager = isManager;
    }
    //Render button or whatever based on IsManager value;
}
```

EDIT: To check if the button needs to be enabled or not:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private bool IsManager;
    public Form2(bool isManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsManager = isManager;
        setButtonVisibility(); //call method setVisibility() -> this is what was missing in your code

    }
    private void setButtonVisibility()
    {
        if(IsManager == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button Message Display");
            //or YourButton.Enable = true; in order to enable it.
        }
    }
}
```

In your second form, there are a couple of issues:

- Class name and constructor name are not the same;
- The parameter for the Form2 constructor is missing;
- isManager should be assigned the value of IsManager which should have been passed as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: ok while trying this solution i get an assignment made to same variable: "did you mean to assign something else?", on this line of code "IsManager = IsManager;"

Comment: @Jaydon the variable names are case sensitive. The line should be IsManager = isManager

Comment: gotcha! thank you!, now second question I thought putting the code to check if it is true or false would go into the: page_Load, but that doesn't seem to work, where would you suggest I check the bool when the form loads so that they are enabled when it loads the form?

Comment: You can enable or disable buttons by adding a new method to the Form2 constructor `SetButtonVisibility()` In this method you will check the value of IsManager, then do something like `if (IsManager == true) { YourButton.Enable = true; }`

Comment: Would That Look Like This:                                                                                 private void setButtonVisibility()
        {
            if(isManager == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Buttons Should Be active");            
            }
        }

Comment: Yes, you can try that and remember to call `setButtonVisibility()` from `Form2` constructor, after the `IsManager = isManager` line

Comment: Ok so this Didn't seem to fix anything on my end so I will update this forums code in the original question and you can tell me if it looks correct or if I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Probably won't see your response for about 8 or so hours so if i don't respond pretty quick thats why, thank you again

Comment: @Jaydon i've edited my answer to include the method `setButtonVisibility()`

Comment: that was supposed to say question not answer.

Comment: no, it's my answer. I've edited my answer to include the code that was missing from your example. Read again...

Comment: I apologize I failed to notice you edited your anwser. thank you again Everything works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading your question I am assuming that you're trying to set a value to the global bool IsManager and want to do some action in the other second form based on this value.

You can achieve this in multiple ways one passes your global bool in the constructor of second form something like this

```
public partial class SecondPage: Form
{
    bool _isManager;
    public SecondPage(bool IsManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       _isManager = IsManager; // the problem was isManager as mistakenkly i used small "i" 
    }
}
```

and from the first form pass value like

```
 private void Button_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.hide();  
    IsManager = true;
    Form2 f2 = new form2(IsManager);
    f2.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Comment: Ok while trying your solution this part of the code:        _isManager = isManager; is highlighted in red and shows does not exist in current context, and with this solution will i need to keep this part of my code:                                                                           
           public static class Global //makes any variables global to be shared across forms
        {
            public static bool IsManager = false; //sets global string
        }

Comment: Though i think you have already got your answer but you needed to replace _isManager =  isManager to _isManager = IsManager. I have edited the answer as well for your. Variables are case sensitve